# Histogram (Reasoning)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

To construct a histogram, which one of the following would you choose to be represented by the horizontal axis?

a)Midpoints
b)Class Boundaries 
c)Class intervals.

Explain your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose class intervals because we assume that in each interval the distribution is uniform, thus nice histogram would consist out of rectangles where their bases are the boundaries of the respective classes and their heights their (relative) frequency.